# Select element that onchange is being triggered from - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a form where when an input has a value put in and then is un-focused it trigger an event.

Here is my code so far.

```
$("#live-form input").on('change', function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var key = $(this).attr("name");
    $.post('update-form.php', {key:value}, function(data) {
        $("#form-status").html(data);
    });
});
```

And my update-form.php script returns the following response for testing only:

Key: *key* - Value: *value*

When I change from my jQuery selector to *#username* it works fine. But otherwise it doesn't at all.

HTML as requested:

```
<div id="form-status"></div>
<form id="live-form" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-contain">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username:" value="" maxlength="32" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that with "doesn't work at all" you mean that the AJAX request never takes place?

Comment: It works fine.. :\ http://jsfiddle.net/8yQP3/

Comment: you should use `$( this ).serialize()` function

Comment: @Jack - I wasn't sure if anything was happening at all.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - I was stuck for ages on it and then I tried it without the ajax and it worked, so i added it back and it work.